# Loading a list of handlers - whether to use properties file or reflection

Tags: java, reflection, properties-file

In the projects that my team is currently working on, we have tens of handlers for a specific event that implement a common interface, and they are invoked when the events they listen to occurs.

And here is the problem: whether we should use a properties file to configure which handlers we currently have or use reflection to list all classes implementing the common interface?

Pros for using a properties file:

- More flexible, easier to disable a specific handler.
- Could have different configuration in different environments.

Pros for using reflections:

- Easier to deploy, no need to maintain the properties file for class addition/removal.
- More error-proof since we don't need to process the plain text in properties file and load them using class loaders.

I am currently hesitating between the two. Is there a commonly perceived `good practice'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the two options, I would vote for using a properties file. It may involve maintaining some more files, but it is always better to have explicit configuration as opposed to implicit configuration. It will also make it much easier for people new to your code base to understand whats going on.

I would also recommend that you use Dependency Injection (Spring or Guice). Spring DI meets your requirements. You can explicitly configure which handlers are used and you can easily have different files for production, UAT, etc. We have a similar pattern and Spring has worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

My vote for properties.

The main reason I can think of is you might have handlers in the classpath that you don't want to use (for what ever reason) or turn on and off